# MYSQL: how to search for fields that hold values sep. by commas?

Tags: mysql

1. **tags** (id_tag,name)
2. **news** (id,title,data,tags)

The field *news>tags* is a *varchar(255)*. Im planning to put data like this in that field: "*1,7,34*"

That means that a particular row in *news* is linked to tags 1, 7 and 34 from the *tags* table.

Then, how can i search for **ALL** *news* records that have the **34** value (among others) in the *tags* field?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Putting the tags into a varchar is just a problem waiting to happen. You should have another table that contains (news_id,tag) values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could fully normalize your table design by adding a third table NewsTags (PKID, news_ID, tag_ID) and fill it thusly (assuming your example news record is record 100):

```
1, 100, 1
1, 100, 7
1, 100, 34
```

Then, for the "how" part of your question, you'd be joining News to NewsTags to Tags, WHERE Tags.TagID = 34

Try it out; I'm sure some sample code will follow..

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this. You can do something along the lines of:

```
select id from news where ','||tags||',' like '%,34,%'
```

or:

```
select id from news where tags like '34,%'
union all select id from news where tags like ',34%'
union all select id from news where tags like '%,34,%'
```

but it will be a horrible hog of resources (as well as looking ugly) because you cannot index parts of columns. Per-row functions in select queries never scale well.

The *right* way to do this is to separate the comma separated values out and follow third normal form (3NF) - all aspiring DBAs really should read up on this concept as should all coders who want to work with and understand databases:

```
tags:
    id_tag
    name
    primary key (id_tag)
news
    id
    title
    data
    primary key (id)
news_tags
    id          foreign key news(id)
    id_tag      foreign key tags(id_tag)
    primary key (id,id_tag)
    index       (id_tag)
```

Then you can use a query like:

```
select n.id from news n, news_tags nt
    where nt.id_tag = 34
      and n.id = nt.id
```

(or its explicit-join equivalent). This will allow the DBMS to efficiently use the indexes you have set up for all the tables.

You should *never* put yourself in the situation where you need to use part of a column for anything, since that inherently destroys scalability. By separating out the tags into separate columns (and making them a true many-to-many relationship by introducing another table), you remove that problem.

All databases should be built in 3NF and only reverted if there's a performance problem and only when you understand the consequences. There are tricks you can use to ensure data integrity (such as insert/update triggers) in those cases but, for a beginner, I would suggest sticking with 3NF.